# Add jquery icon to html test which is clickable

Tags: jquery, html

how can i add a icon [+] at the last of the statement so that if i click a icon i can get a alert.

```
<div id="catalog" style="width: 518px;">
      <ul id="catalog111" style="left: -37px;top:       -140px;width=500%;">
        <li class="ui-state-default" style="list-style:square; margin: 5px; padding: 5px;
  color: black; background-color: #A0A0A0; width: 441px; font-size: 12px;color: #313b3b"  
    >I should be able to select a document to upload into system  'Need Icon'</li>

      </ul>

   </div>​
```

Comment: last of the statement in a sense end of div tag? and for the icon you prefer an img tag with a picture included?

Comment: @Swarnajith : last of the statement means end of the 'li' i.e end of this statement "I should be able to select a document to upload into system"[+] where [+] is clickable .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this,

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#plus').click(function(){
        alert('+ sign clicked');
    });
});                
</script>
```

You can put a link at the end of the statement with a hypherlink,

```
<div id="catalog" style="width: 518px;">
      <ul id="catalog111" style="left: -37px;top: -140px;width=500%;">
        <li class="ui-state-default" style="list-style:square; margin: 5px; padding: 5px; color: black; background-color: #A0A0A0; width: 441px; font-size: 12px;color: #313b3b">I should be able to select a document to upload into system <a href="#" id="plus" style="text-decoration:none">[+]</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>​
```